# Django Formset not working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I was experimenting with the formsets provided in django forms.
Here is the forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NewForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Username")
email = forms.EmailField(label="email")
city = forms.CharField(label="city")
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from .forms import NewForm
from django.forms import formset_factory


def formview(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
  form  = NewForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
                    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                    city = form.cleaned_data['city']
                    email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                    print(type(form.cleaned_data))
                    NewFormSet = formset_factory(NewForm)
                    formset = NewFormSet()
                    for form in formset:
                            print(form)
                    for k,v in  form.cleaned_data.items():
                            print(k,v)
    else:
            print("ddd")
            form = NewForm()
            formset = 0
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form,'formset':formset})
```

Earlier it was working fine
But The thing is when I added this formset code it showed error

Template:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>The Form</title>
</head>

<body>
   <form method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    {{ field.error }}
    <br />
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}
    <br />
    {% endfor %}    
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
    {% for f in formset %}
      <form method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
       {% for field in f %}
      {{ f.error }}<br />
      {{ f.label }}
      {{ f }}
      <br />
       {% endfor %} 
   </form>
   {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `form.is_valid()` to get it cleaned/validated, before that it has no `cleaned_data`, you should also consider renaming the loop variable because you already have a variable named `form`:

```
for newform in formset:
    if newform.is_valid():
        for k,v in newform.cleaned_data.items():
            print(k,v)
```

You can also call `is_valid()` on the formset to validate all forms in the formset:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    for newform in formset:
        for k,v in newform.cleaned_data.items():
           print(k,v)
```

But keep in mind that `newform` at that point has no data, it's just an empty `NewForm`.

EDIT:

See also [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#validating-the-number-of-forms-in-a-formset) for formset validation and errors, and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) how to use them easily in a template.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was

```
def formview(request):
     newformset = formset_factory(NewForm)
     if form.is_valid():
         formset = newformset(request.POST)
         ..
          ...
         ...

     else:
         formset = newformset()
```